# parameter count mismatch exception thrown when event handler of button called from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a few textboxes on a page whose values are getting populated from the return value of 
a modal window like this and I have a javascript method that calls the event handler of a button in the following way. The values are being returned properly and the textbox is getting populated properly but i am getting an exception parameter count mismatch.

```
 res = window.showModalDialog('frm_VisitorSearchPopUp.aspx', "", "dialogWidth:1024px;dialogHeight:600px");
getElementById('<%=AddVisitorID.ClientID %>').click();
```

This problem does not occur when i am using window.open() method can anybody tell me why this problem is occurring.
My Code

```
function openup() {
    var left = screen.width / 2 - 1024 / 2;
    var tops = screen.height / 2 - 600 / 2;
    var d = new Date();
    var res;
    res = window.showModalDialog('frm_VisitorSearchPopUp.aspx', "", "dialogWidth:1024px;dialogHeight:600px");
    setvalues(res.PersonName, res.Address, res.CompanyName, res.ContactNumber, res.Email);
}

function setvalues(PersonName, Address, CompanyName, ContactNumber, Email) {
    var RowId = $("#<%= VisitorDetailsGrid.ClientID%>").getDataIDs();
    for (i = 0; i < RowId.length; i++) {
        rowData = $("#<%= VisitorDetailsGrid.ClientID%>").getRowData(RowId[i]);
        if (rowData.PersonName == PersonName && rowData.ContactNumber == ContactNumber && rowData.CompanyName == CompanyName && rowData.Email == Email && rowData.Address == Address) {
            alert("The visitor \"" + PersonName + "\" has already been added to the visitor's list.");
            document.getElementById('<%=PersonNameID.ClientID%>').value = "";
            document.getElementById('<%=AddressID.ClientID%>').value = "";
            document.getElementById('<%=CompanyNameID.ClientID%>').value = "";
            document.getElementById('<%=ContactNumberID.ClientID%>').value = "";
            document.getElementById('<%=EmailID.ClientID%>').value = "";
            return;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('<%=PersonNameID.ClientID%>').value = PersonName;
    document.getElementById('<%=AddressID.ClientID%>').value = Address;
    document.getElementById('<%=CompanyNameID.ClientID%>').value = CompanyName;
    document.getElementById('<%=ContactNumberID.ClientID%>').value = ContactNumber;
    document.getElementById('<%=EmailID.ClientID%>').value = Email;
    elem = document.getElementById('<%=AddVisitorID.ClientID %>').click();        


}
```